# Javascript Array data (in socket IO application)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io

First of all, here's my code:

```
var users = {};

//User Connect
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('connected');
    socket.on('session', function (session){

     users[socket.id] = [session, socket];
     console.log(users);
     socket.emit("session_established");

     //User Disconnect
     socket.on('disconnect', function (){ 
         delete users[socket.id];
         socket.broadcast.emit('disconnect', { data : session});
    }); 


    //The above all works as it should, now here it what I want to do:

    socket.on('chatMessage', function (message, userID) {
    users[userIDsSocket][userID].emit('chatMessageResponse', { data: message});
    });


    });    
});
```

Here's what my data looks like, (and this is for one user):

```
{ '17819180631362480757': //this value is users[socket.id]
[ '1',               //this value is session at the top, and in the bottom part userID 
 { id: '17819180631362480757', //The rest of this is the socket data
   namespace: [Object],
   manager: [Object],
   disconnected: false,
   ackPackets: 0,
   acks: {},
   flags: [Object],
   readable: true,
   store: [Object],
   _events: [Object] } ] }
```

so this is kind of what I need to do (Just in english terms of how it should function):

oh and first, there can be multiple userID's/Session that are the same, if the user has the window open in more than one tab/computer/device, so it needs to send it to every socket that has the same userID

```
socket.on('chatMessage', function (message, userID) {  

for each (users[*].userID==userID)
{
    users[*][userID].emit('chatMessageResponse', { data: message});
}
});
```

So I don't know how I would go through each part disregarding socket.id (where i placed [*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
users[socket.id] = {userID:session, socketID:socket};
```

then:

```
for (var key in users)
{
if (users[key].userID==userID)
{

users[key].socketID.emit('new_request_response', { data: message});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want a `for in` loop, with an `if` condition.

```
socket.on('chatMessage', function (message, userID) {
    for (var key in users)
        if (users[key].userId==userId)
            users[key][userId].emit('chatMessageResponse', { data: message});
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it to work, I can get it to do this and send it to everyone that is connected, however there is no userID listed, so that's not calling anything

Comment: awesome. The one thing you want to look out for when using `for in` is that you might get it looping on a property you don't expect, like a prototype method or something, so it might be safest to add another if condition, like if `(object.hasOwnProperty(key))` Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

here is my code.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(15630);
var clients = [];
var coupling = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

clients[socket.id] = socket;
socket.on('setUserID', function (userID) {

    socket.set('userID', userID, function () {
        coupling[userID] = socket.id;
    });

});


for (var client in io.sockets.clients()) {

        console.log(client);

}

socket.on('send', function (from,to,message)
{

    var sender = 0;
    socket.get('userID', function (err, name) {
        sender = name;
    });
    var userSocket = clients[coupling[to]];
    if(userSocket != null || userSocket != undefined)
    userSocket.emit('message', {from :from,to : to,message:message});
});
socket.on('disconnect', function () {

    var sender = 0;
    socket.get('userID', function (err, name) {
        sender = name;
    });
    delete clients[coupling[sender]]
    //var userSocket = clients[coupling[sender]];
    //if(userSocket != null || userSocket != undefined)
    //clients[coupling[sender]] = null;
});
```

});